# Setting header color of one column in AdvancedDataGrid doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

Need help with this issue. I need to change header color.
The following doesn't work:

```
column.setStyle(StyleNames.HEADER_COLORS, "#FF7F00");
```

Comment: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/01/23/setting-the-column-header-text-color-on-a-datagrid-control-in-flex/

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way to set the background color of just one column's header in the `AdvancedDataGrid`. You'll need to use a custom renderer for the header.

**Usage**

```
<fx:Style>
    .yellowHeaderStyle {
        backgroundColor: yellow;
        backgroundAlpha: 1.0;
    }
</fx:Style>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{dataProvider}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="firstname" headerText="Firstname" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="lastname" headerText="Lastname"
            headerRenderer="com.example.ColoredHeaderRenderer" headerStyleName="yellowHeaderStyle" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

**ColoredHeaderRenderer**

```
package com.example
{
    import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;

    [Style(name="backgroundColor", type="uint", format="Color")]
    [Style(name="backgroundAlpha", type="Number")]

    /**
     * The ColoredHeaderRenderer extends the default header renderer for a AdvancedDataGrid
     * control and adds styles for chaning the backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha.
     * 
     * <p>Both styles (backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha) must me set.</p>  
     */
    public class ColoredHeaderRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer
    {
        private var grid:AdvancedDataGrid;

        override public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void
        {
            super.listData = value;
            grid = AdvancedDataGrid(value.owner);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            if (background)
            {
                background.graphics.clear();
                background.graphics.beginFill(getStyle("backgroundColor"), getStyle("backgroundAlpha"));

                // The function AdvancedDataGridBase.createHeaders() adds a padding to the top
                // and bottom of the HeaderRenderer. Let's undo this...
                background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0 - grid.getStyle("paddingTop"), unscaledWidth,
                    unscaledHeight + grid.getStyle("paddingTop") + grid.getStyle("paddingBottom") - 1);
                background.graphics.endFill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```